# the d3 is not able to select the element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, d3.js

Here I have used ngfor to iterate over my API response and fill up my table and I have a div in one of the hidden rows that I want to select using d3 to make visualizations, but d3 doesn't select the div when it's inside the <ng-container> I have already figured out the reason of the problem, it's because of the API response if I use some static array like [0,1,2] d3 selects the div but is unable for the API response, what should I do. The div I want to select is the:
`<div id="court-container"\>`
`this.fetchApiResponse();`

component.ty:

```
 import {
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  OnDestroy,
  OnInit,

  ViewChild,

  ViewEncapsulation
} from '@angular/core';

import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { UntilDestroy, untilDestroyed } from '@ngneat/until-destroy';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { PlayersService } from '../_services/players.service';


@UntilDestroy()
@Component({
  selector: 'player-summary-component',
  templateUrl: './player-summary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./player-summary.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class PlayerSummaryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  
  @ViewChild('courtContainer') courtContainer: ElementRef;


  endpoint: any;
  apiResponse: any;
  isRowExpanded: boolean[] = [];
  columnCount = 20; // Set this to the number of columns in your table

  toggleRow(index: number) {
    this.isRowExpanded[index] = !this.isRowExpanded[index];
  }
  playerID: number = 1;
  gameID: number = 0;
  courtDrawn: boolean = false;
  private dataReadySubject = new Subject<void>();
  dataReady$ = this.dataReadySubject.asObservable();
  

  constructor(
    protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    protected cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    protected playersService: PlayersService,
    private el: ElementRef
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchApiResponse();

    
    
    
    
    
    }
    
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this.dataReady$.pipe(untilDestroyed(this)).subscribe(() => {
        if (this.courtDrawn) {
          this.removeExistingCourt();
        } 
        const courtContainer = d3.select("#court-container");
        
        this.drawCourt(this.apiResponse?.games[0].shots,courtContainer);

        console.log("Court container element:", courtContainer);
console.log("Shots data:", this.apiResponse?.games[0].shots);

      });
    }
    
    
  
  changeParams(): void {
    this.fetchApiResponse();
    
  }

  fetchApiResponse(): void {
    this.playersService.getPlayerSummary(this.playerID).pipe(untilDestroyed(this)).subscribe(data => {
      this.endpoint = data.endpoint;
      console.log("endpoint", this.endpoint);
      
      this.apiResponse = data.apiResponse;
    
      // this.drawCourt(this.apiResponse?.games[0].shots);
      this.dataReadySubject.next();
     

      
      
       
      
    
    }
    );
  }
```

```
  <tbody>
                      <ng-container
                        *ngFor="let game of apiResponse?.games; let i = index"
                      >
                        <tr [id]="'row-' + i">
                          <td class="left hidden">{{ game.date }}</td>
                          <td class="left first__left">{{ game.isStarter }}</td>
                          <td class="left">{{ game.minutes }}</td>
                          <td class="left"></td>
                          <td class="left hidden">{{ game.points }}</td>
                          <td class="right highlight highlight--first switch">
                            {{ game.assists }}
                          </td>
                          <td class="right highlight highlight switch">
                            {{ game.offensiveRebounds }}
                          </td>
                          <td class="right highlight highlight --last switch">
                            {{ game.defensiveRebounds }}
                          </td>
                          <td class="right switch">{{ game.steals }}</td>
                          <td class="right switch">{{ game.blocks }}</td>
                          <td class="right switch">{{ game.turnovers }}</td>
                          <td class="right switch">
                            {{ game.defensiveFouls }}
                          </td>
                          <td class="right switch">
                            {{ game.offensiveFouls }}
                          </td>
                          <td class="right switch">
                            {{ game.freeThrowsMade }}
                          </td>
                          <td class="right switch">
                            {{ game.freeThrowsAttempted }}
                          </td>
                          <td class="right switch">
                            {{ game.twoPointersMade }}
                          </td>
                          <td class="right switch">
                            {{ game.twoPointersAttempted }}
                          </td>
                          <td class="right switch">
                            {{ game.threePointersMade }}
                          </td>
                          <td class="right switch">
                            {{ game.threePointersAttempted }}
                          </td>
                          <td class="right switch" (click)="toggleRow(i)">
                            {{ isRowExpanded[i] ? "▲" : "▼" }}
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr
                          [id]="'expanded-row-' + i"
                          [style.display]="
                            isRowExpanded[i] ? 'table-row' : 'none'
                          "
                        >
                          <td [attr.colspan]="columnCount">
                            <div id="court-container" >dwewedwed</div>

                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </ng-container>
                    </tbody>
```

I've tried using ngAfterViewInit where I select the div and wait for the API response to be rendered in HTML but so far nothing has worked.

Comment: creating a separate dumb component would be a better way for that div as then you'll be able to run your logic whenever it renders but for now, did you try putting that d3.select code inside a setTimout? right now you're fetching the data and trying to access that div element after that right away but at that point, browser repaint haven't really happened so to make sure you run your code after the repaint, you can put it in a setTimout. one more thing, putting that dataReady$ subscription inside ngAfterViewInit is kinda useless, you can move that to ngOnInit.